# VMware Converter conversion of Windows TeamCity Server

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-converter, teamcity

I have a VM: Windows Server 2008 running TeamCity with a local MSSQL database, virtualized using Hyper-V.  I want to migrate this VM to ESXi (free version) using VMware Converter.  The VM has a reserved DHCP address, and I would like to keep the same IP to keep things simple.  I plan to use netsh to dump the NIC settings to a file and import them after the conversion so that I can keep the IP address, and the DNS records that point to this server won't need to be changed.  I also plan to disable encryption/SSL on the transfer to speed it up.

Lastly, I want to increase the hard disk size and allocate more RAM to the new VM.  Reading up on the subject it seems like it should go smoothly.  Is there anything I should be aware of?  Am I inline with best practices for this type of operation?

Comment: DHCP reservation will require you keep the same MAC, which is fine. DNS will be ok as well, as you'll still have same server name/IP after the move. Once you've converted the VM, before you fire it up, you can change the settings, and allocate more RAM etc. The good thing about doing it this way is if anything goes wrong you still have the original VM to fall back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went fine, except there was no visible way to increase the size of the vmdk when I created the virtual machine.